# uninstalling global typing not allowing me to reinstall

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have installed the moment typing globally using `typings install dt~moment --save --global`

Running `typings list` gives me:

```
├── lodash@4.0.0
├── es6-shim (global)
└── moment (global)
```

I have since decided to uninstall it using `typings uninstall moment --global`

Running `typings list` gives me:

```
├── lodash@4.0.0
└── es6-shim (global)
```

Now I go to install in current directory using `typings install dt~moment --save` and get the following error:

`typings ERR! message Attempted to compile "moment" as an external module, but it looks like a global module. You'll need to enable the global option to continue.`

Why on earth is that happening, I have also tried to clear-cache previously which didn't help.

```
node v5
npm v3.3.9
tsc v1.8.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: 
If you upgrade to typescript 2.0 you could install typings with npm.

```
npm install @types/moment
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/ https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/moment

Maybe that helps.

Comment: i am no trying to install it globally, im trying to uninstall it globally and install just locally

Comment: I don't think you can. I might be wrong but it seems like moment can only be installed as global. Found this definition of when to install global or local: "A module definition is considered "external" if it has an import or export declaration at the top-level. Everything else can be considered "global"."
Moment does seem to lack exports and imports at top level, so I think it can only be installed globally. 
Source: https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/faq.md (Types of Typings)

Comment: If you upgrade to typescript 2.0 you could install typings with npm. 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/moment
Maybe that helps more.

Comment: Using `npm install @types/moment` works perfectly, if you updated your answer to include that I will mark as correct.

Comment: I changed it completely since I misunderstood you first. Glad that it worked.